# Re-POST-ing a form using Ajax, for back/fwd history, in jQuery Mobile

Tags: forms, post, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I'm investigating the suitability of the jQM history management for my organization's mobile web site. Part of our requirement is that when a user posts a form, it posts using Ajax. When a user taps "back" and then "forward" browser buttons, we need to re-post the form using Ajax again. Here's a diagram:

1. [home.php: post to new.php] =>
2. [new.php: post to list.php] =>
3. [from list.php, click back twice to home.php] =>
4. [* home.php: click fwd, does a GET request to new.php *] =>
5. [* new.php: click fwd, does a GET request to list.php *]

[*] not the behavior I want. I want to re-POST data from steps 1 and 2

During steps 4 and 5, I want to intercept the jQM execution at the "pagebeforeload" event (seems like the right place), and modify the data.options.data (to include the serialized post data) and data.options.type (to POST) properties of the data object which is passed to the event handler. Then I'd let the pageload process move on with the modified values. This, I think, would give me the behavior I want.

So far, I see that I can intercept the pagebeforeload event and modify the values with the below event handler:

```js
$(document).bind("pagebeforeload",
    function( e, data ) {
        console.log(data.toPage);
        console.log(data.options);
        data.options.type = "POST";
        data.options.data = "edit=Hanford";
    }
);
```

But the missing piece is, how can I "store" the information in steps 1 and 2, such that when I intercept the pagebeforeload event in 4 and 5, I can know to modify the "type" and "data" properties properly.

I've made a jquery/browser History prototype to illustrate the behavior I would like to get from jQuery Mobile. The JavaScript is:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    //listen to the history popstate event
    $(window).bind('popstate',
    function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.state && e.originalEvent.state.type && e.originalEvent.state.type == "post") {
            //do an ajax post based on what is stored in history state
            $.post(e.originalEvent.state.path,
            e.originalEvent.state.data,
            function(data) {jaxer(data,'POST')});
        } else if (e.originalEvent.state !== undefined){
            //do an ajax get
            $.get(location.pathname,
            function(data) {jaxer(data,'GET')});
        }
    });
    //add event listeners
    addClickHandler();
});
function jaxer(data, msg) {
        if (msg) {console.log(msg+' request made using ajax');}
        $('#slider')[0].innerHTML = data;
        addClickHandler();
}

//hijax hyperlinks and form submissions
function addClickHandler() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        history.pushState({
            path: this.path
        },
        '', this.href);
        $.get(this.href,
       function(data) {jaxer(data,'GET')});
       e.preventDefault()
    });
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        console.log('saving serialized form data into historyState: '+formData);
        history.pushState({path: this.action, data: formData, type: "post"},'',this.action);
        $.post(this.action,
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {jaxer(data,'POST')});
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //add the form submit button to the form as a hidden input such that it will get serialized
    $('form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        $(this.form).append("<input type='hidden' name='" + this.name + "' value='" + this.value + "'/>");
    });
    console.log("event handlers added to DOM");
};
```

When a user-initiated POST occurs, I put the serialized POST data into the history's state object. Then, when a popstate event occurs, I can query the state object for this information. If I find it, then I can perform an ajax POST. I would like to get the same functionality within the jQuery Mobile history handling. That way I can take advantage of the page change animations, etc.

Comment: This is going to seem like a simplistic answer, but, have you considered simply adding the attribute data-ajax="false" to the form tag and letting things work normally?

Comment: That won't work for us. We are primarily navigating users in our site via POST requests (backend requirement). But we want to use Ajax for the site speed and usability benefits.